# Simple live HTML editing via AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to get together a simple little website, on which I can edit a number. This change (onblur) will be send to a PHP script via AJAX, writing the edited number back into the HTML file.

I got this far, but can't get PHP and DOMXpath to work.

Website (index.html):

```
<div class="actualcount" contenteditable="true">254</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "save.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {postdata: $(".actualcount").html()} ,
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
     $editData = $_POST['postdata'];
     $newText = '<div class="actualcount" contenteditable="true">'.$editData.'</div>';
     $html = file_get_contents('index.html');
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     $dom->loadHTML($html);
     $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
     $actualcount = $xpath->query('//*[@class="actualcount"]')->item(0);
     $actualcount->parentNode->replaceChild($newText, $actualcount);
     $dom->saveHTMLFile("index.html");
?>
```

It gives me an

> Fatal Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   DOMNode::replaceChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given ...

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replaceChild takes 2 node elements as arguments , the first one you passed was a string ! you need to create an element instead.

here's a simple example of how to do that with [DOMDocument::createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) and [DOMElement::setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php)

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['postdata'])) {
         $editData = (string) $_POST['postdata']; 
     } else {
         $editData = '';
     }

     $html = file_get_contents('index.html');
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
     libxml_clear_errors();
     $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
     $actualcount = $xpath->query('//*[@class="actualcount"]')->item(0);
     $newnode = $dom->createElement('div', $editData); 
     $newnode->setAttribute("class", "actualcount");
     $newnode->setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
     $actualcount->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $actualcount);
     $dom->saveHTMLFile("index.html");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much azjezz, this was the solution. And it looks like I didn't get the concept of DOMXpath/DOMDocument yet, so thank you again for pointing me in the right direction. Best regards